# Prefix "a" in "amaze"

Tags: prefixes

Usually the prefix "a" means "not" or "without", for example: atheist, anarchy. But, in "amaze" it's not the case, since the word *maze* means "confusing" or "labyrinth" and "amaze" means "surprise". Is there another meaning to the prefix "a"? Or, is it not a prefix in this word?

Comment: Related: [What is the history of adding the a- prefix to form words?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13661/what-is-the-history-of-adding-the-a-prefix-to-form-words)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=amaze) reports the following:

> early 13c., amasian "stupefy, make crazy," from a-, probably used here as an intensive prefix, + -masian, related to maze (q.v.). Sense of "overwhelm with wonder" is from 1580s.

So the *a-* is a prefix here, but it intensifies instead of negating.  [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/a-) lists the several uses of *a-* and notes the Greek-based meaning you cite as the only one that remains productive today.

Comment: I would also think the word muse has the same roots. "Amuse" then might be to say without thoughts on, which could be said 'speechless' in our culture.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprise that Wiktionary does not have a sense of "to the" which I have understood to be another use of *a-*.

And I think it's productive, as well, as I use it to make new words, though admittedly ones that sound archaic.

How about ...

> a-swimming we will go...?

Usually hyphenated, this would be my understanding of the use in amaze: "to the maze" = "to confuse my mind (with the sheer wonder of it!)"

Is there no reference that agrees with this?

Comment: Wiktionary now [has `a-` as a prefix meaning 'toward'](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/a-#Prefix_2) [in two senses](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/a-#Prefix_6)

Answer (score 1):

See etymonline (http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=amaze):

> early 13c., amasian "stupefy, make crazy," from a-, probably used here as an intensive prefix, + -masian, related to maze