# Use of "a-" before words, not the indefinite article

Tags: prefixes

Sometimes I've found some words that start with an "a-" prefix, not the indefinite article. I think it's used to make the phrasing more euphonic and more "melodic", at least this is what it sounds to me.
For instance:
[image: a-tumbling]
How is it called and is it common?

Comment: It's archaic, a relic of the old participial prefix. Only occurs in old texts, local dialects, and dramas about them.

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13661/what-is-the-history-of-adding-the-a-prefix-to-form-words (and others).

Comment: ***A-prefixing***: Yale Grammatical Diversity Project 
English in North America : https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/a-prefixing

Comment: The actual term 'a-prefixing' has been given in at least two previous threads.

Comment: This has been done here so many times...

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions!